# Error whilst aptitude upgrade > error processing install-info

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I've encountered a strange issue whilst updating my debian jessie system.  I do a `aptitude update`, `aptitude upgrade` which then throws a `error processing install-info`.
I managed to find the solution on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), but wanted to post it here so it is as publically available as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple move of the affected file:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst.bad
```

To undo the move:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst.bad /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst
```